# Trying to read Outlook Email Attachment which has a Hyperlink

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to automate a process using Python and Outlook. I am able to login successfully and able to read the last message received in the "My Folder Name" Folder  but for some reason I am not able to read the attachment contents like I want to copy the hyperlink present in the email attachment but doesn't gives the contents of the email.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("My Shared Mailbox Name")
inbox = folder.Folders("My Folder Name")
email = inbox.Items
lastemail = email.GetLast()
body_content = lastemail.body
print (body_content)

attachment_content = lastemail.Attachments

print (attachment_content)
```

It gives below message  for the last two lines of code:

```
<COMObject <unknown>>
```

The code works until 'print (body_content)' as I can see the body of the last email but it's attachment contents are not readable.

attachment_content = lastemail.Attachments

print (attachment_content) doesn't works.

Right now I have to manually go to the email attachment and copy the hyperlink.
Please let me know where to look, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a pointer to a COM object, which is really meaningless.

Loop through the attachments, and save each one using `Attachment.SaveAsFile`. You can then read the attachment contents from a file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am now able to download the attachment email content as a text file using below code                                                 
    attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\sample.txt') but when I am opening this txt file manually in notepad it has a very different format and doesn't match with the text or hyperlink in the attachment. I also tried printing the attachment it shows the junk data. Please let me know where to look., Thank you

Comment: Is that really a txt attachment? What is the value of the Attachment.Filename property?